# GWEN - Intermittent issue in finding web element in Gwen framework even after wait conditions

Tags: automation-testing

I am using GWEN automation framework to test our web application

Code:

And  dropdown value can be located by xpath "//*[@class='scrollingMenu' or @class='pickListMenu' or @role='listbox'][contains(@style,'visibility: inherit')]//*[text()[normalize-space()="ABC"]]"
And  I wait for dropdown value
And  I click dropdown value

Error:

Could not locate element: dropdown value [locator: xpath=//*[@class='scrollingMenu' or @class='pickListMenu' or @role='listbox'][contains(@style,'visibility: inherit')]//*[text()[normalize-space()="ABC"]]]

Why it is happening intermittently and working most of the time

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically rendered elements are best located by JavaScript. Either convert your locator to a JS equivalent or try enabling the implicit JS locator mechanism. See https://gweninterpreter.org/docs/advanced/implicit-js-locators